# Can the surface area of an object, such as a sphere, tell me its volume, meaning, do all equals surface areas produce the same volume in 3d?

Tags: geometry

Just curious is there is a proof contradicting that of if for a given surface the volume must be the same.

Comment: No this is not true,  the sphere has the biggest volume of all geometric objects if the surface considered the same.

Comment: Just think of rectangular boxes with the same surface area. Do they all have the same volume?

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip I feel dumb, but if you increase  the surface the volume increases, correct?

Comment: One counter example in 2 dimensions is the problem of Dido.

Comment: @EddieBravo Consider very short box with a very big square base. Make the base (and hence the surface area) as big as  you like. Then make the height so small that the volume is as small as you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a unit cube: each side is $1$ unit long. The surface area is $6$ square units, the volume is $1$ cubic unit.

Now consider a rectangular box whose base is $2\times 1$ units, and with a height of $\frac{1}{3}$ unit. The volume is $\frac{2}{3}$ cubic units. The surface area is: two faces of size $2\times 1$, two faces of size $\frac{1}{3}\times 1$, and two faces of size $2\times\frac{1}{3}$. This add ups to $2+2+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2}{3} = 6$ square units, the same as the cube.

So that gives you two solids with the same surface area but different volumes.

In general, of all solid shapes with a given surface area, the sphere with that surface area has the largest volume. And of all solid shapes with a given volume, the sphere with that volume has the smallest surface area.